# Closed form for solution of ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Suppose that $g$ is defined over $\mathbb R$ and

$$f'(x) = g(x) \, (g'(x))^2.$$

Is it possible to find a closed form for the indefinite integral $f$ as a function of $g$?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I don't have a proof